# A variant of the Hungarian algorithm / assignment problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Is there an algorithm for the following variant of the assignment problem:

Suppose we have $n$ workers $A_i$ and $m$ tasks and each worker $A_i$ has to do exactly $t_i$ tasks. (The numbers are chosen such that $m= \sum_{i=1}^n t_i$.) For any $i$ let $C_i$ be the sum of the costs of worker $A_i$. I am searching for an assignment such that $\max_i C_i$ is minimal.

I have found [this variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357571/hungarian-algorithm-with-different-metric), but this deals only with the maximal cost of one task, not with the sum of the tasks for one worker.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem via integer programming. Let $x_{ij}$ be decision variable for the worker $A_i$ do the task $j$ and $c_{ij}$ be the cost of worker $A_i$ do the task $j$. We have $C_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^mc_{ij}x_{ij}$. We need to solve the following IP: 
$\min z$ subject to $\sum\limits_{j=1}^mx_{ij} = t_i$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^mc_{ij}x_{ij} \leq z$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$, and $x_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If all $t_i$s are $1$, then (as said in the linked post), the problem becomes a perfect matching problem. Which is easy to solve.

But here, because you take a $\max$ of a sum of costs, this would translate into a hypergraph matching (where the hyperedges are, for a worker, the groups of tasks whose sum is below the threshold), which ([in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall-type_theorems_for_hypergraphs)) is much harder. You can't directly prove that the hardness of general hypergraph matching translates to this problem, because you can't encode general hypergraphs as arising from this problem ; but it looks like bad news...

If the $t_i$ aren't fixed (but instead we only insist that each task is assigned exactly once), this is the Santa Claus problem (but instead of giving tasks, you give presents ! Way nicer), which is difficult but [has an approximation algorithm](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611975994.167).